# ggplot refuses to forget loop of plots from my previous project

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have no idea what's going on, I never got this problem before, but I'm working on a new project and whenever I try to call `grid.arrange` or any kind of plot now in a loop of plots, R displays the plots from my last project which I obviously don't want anymore which is the last time I used grid.arrange. It refuses to display all of the plots together and I have to go through all of them one by one. It doesn't make sense since my computer has turned off and logged on with new updates since the last time I was working on that project. I tried `rm=ls()` and I still get the same problem. Help :/

Comment: Try to checkout if you have a .RData file in the default folder (project folder/ home folder). It will be automatically loaded each time you started the new session.

Answer (score 1):

the function is `rm(list=ls())`. You could also try `file.remove(".RData")` in the working directory.